# Sorting Outputs of a List Into Different <UL> Tags Django Template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have the following code in one of my templates. As you can see, there is a lot of repetition going on. Hence, I am wondering if I can somehow use Django Template to consolidate this code while achieving the same (or closely comparable) result when it comes to HTML. Namely, I am interested if I can sort the `todo` entries into two different `<ul>` tags on the page, depending on the boolean value of `todo.todo_completed`.

```
{% block content %}
{% if todo_list %}
    <ul class="list-group">
    {% for todo in todo_list %}
        {% if not todo.todo_completed %}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <a href="{% url 'list:todo-detail' todo.id %}" >{{ todo.todo_name }}</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <a href="{% url 'list:todo-complete' todo.id %}">{% bootstrap_icon "ok" %}</a>

                    <a href="{% url 'list:todo-delete' todo.id  %}">{% bootstrap_icon "remove-circle" %}</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <ul class="list-group">
    {% for todo in todo_list %}
        {% if todo.todo_completed %}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <a href="{% url 'list:todo-detail' todo.id %}" class="text-muted">{{ todo.todo_name }}</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <a href="{% url 'list:todo-complete' todo.id %}">{% bootstrap_icon "ok" %}</a>

                    <a href="{% url 'list:todo-delete' todo.id  %}">{% bootstrap_icon "remove-circle" %}</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but writing a template tag is usually the answer to removing duplication in templates.

Comment: Basically, I was trying to do it in one `{% for %}` loop instead of two.

Comment: Can't be done with your current structure `<ul>for-loop1</ul><ul>for-loop2</ul>` (it would require the template engine to be able to delay the output of the second `ul` until the end of the loop).

Comment: Are you telling me that if I want two different `ul` or `div` then it cannot be done? That is essentially my question.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, if the for-loops are _inside_ sibling elements then there are no way to combine them into a single for-loop. You can always split the list in your view (or create a template tag)..